# Laravel 5.2 secondary mysql database connections returns default connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to connect with a second mysql database with Laravel 5.2.

database.php config:

```
[
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'primary'),
    'connections' => [
        'primary' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', ''),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'secondary' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'secondary.host',
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],
];
```

Code:

```
<?php


namespace App\Objects;

use DB;

class Test
{
    private $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = DB::connection('secondary');
        // Read stuff from the secondary database, for example:
        dump($this->db->select('SELECT * FROM addresses LIMIT 1;'));
    }
}
```

Somehow the connection `DB::connection('secondary')` returns is my primary database connection.

After digging deep into the laravel core, I've noticed: that the `Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::createConnection` returns an incorrect connection.

Comment: show some details of your next move or what you are doing with this connection

Comment: The secondary database will be an externaly updated database where i have read only access and is filled with addresses. At the moment i'll be happy if i can get a `DB::connection('secondary')->select('SHOW TABLES;');` working, so i can continue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify connection for each query:

```
DB::connection('secondary')->table('users')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Comment: I've tried this, but a `DB::connection('secondary')->select('SHOW TABLES;');` shows the tables of my primary database server, not the secondary.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same env variables for both connections. You need to have different variables for each connection:

```
DB_DATABASE_PRIMARY
DB_DATABASE_SECONDARY
```

example for all other variables.

Comment: My user/pass/databasename are all the same, 
only the host is different and that one is written in the config file it self, not the env file.

Comment: yeah, I just noticed. That's very weird since your config and a code are correct. Did you `artisan config:cache`? just for the sake of it, also try to set the `$connection` property on a model and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah i did `config:cache`, even did a `config:clear`